# @feathersjs Server Multiple JWT Authentication Services Not Allowed?

Tags: feathersjs, feathers-authentication

I'm looking for an answer to best practices for this solution. I have an IOT project im working on that requires authentication on two paths. User and device.

What I am attempting to do is have full control over route authentication separately on user and device so i thought that creating two separate JWT services would be appropriate.

Feathers: 4.5.8
My authentication Service looks like this

```
export default function (app: Application): void {

  const deviceAuthentication = new DeviceAuthService(app, 'device-authentication');
  deviceAuthentication.register('device-jwt', new DeviceJWTStrategy());
  deviceAuthentication.register('device', new DeviceStrategy());

  const authentication = new AuthService(app, 'authentication');
  authentication.register('jwt', new JWTStrategy());
  authentication.register('local', new LocalStrategy());


  app.use('/device-authentication', deviceAuthentication);
  app.use('/authentication', authentication);

  app.configure(expressOauth());
}
//hooks /someapi
{before:{ get: [authenticate('device-jwt')]}

//config

  "device-authentication": {
    "entity": "device",
    "service": "devices",
    "secret": "***",
    "authStrategies": [
      "device-jwt",
      "device"
    ],
    "device": {
      "usernameField": "uuid",
      "altUsernameField": "email",
      "passwordField": "password"
    },
    "jwtOptions": {
      "header": {
        "typ": "access"
      },
      "audience": "https://something.com",
      "issuer": "feathers",
      "algorithm": "HS256",
      "expiresIn": "1d"
    }
  },
  "authentication": {
    "entity": "user",
    "service": "users",
    "secret": "*****",
    "authStrategies": [
      "jwt",
      "local"
    ],
    "jwtOptions": {
      "header": {
        "typ": "access"
      },
      "audience": "https://somthing.com",
      "issuer": "feathers",
      "algorithm": "HS256",
      "expiresIn": "1d"
    },
    "local": {
      "usernameField": "email",
      "passwordField": "password"
    },
    "oauth": {
      "redirect": "/",
      "auth0": {
        "key": "<auth0 oauth key>",
        "secret": "<auth0 oauth secret>",
        "subdomain": "<auth0 subdomain>"
      },
      "google": {
        "key": "<google oauth key>",
        "secret": "<google oauth secret>",
        "scope": [
          "email",
          "profile",
          "openid"
        ]
      },
      "facebook": {
        "key": "<facebook oauth key>",
        "secret": "<facebook oauth secret>"
      },
      "twitter": {
        "key": "<twitter oauth key>",
        "secret": "<twitter oauth secret>"
      },
      "github": {
        "key": "<github oauth key>",
        "secret": "<github oauth secret>"
      }
    }
  },
```

The problem I am running into is that when i use GET on users, I expect to authenticate on the jwt strategy for the /authentication service. Debugging says i am parsing to the jwt strategy but get a result as see here

`Invalid authentication information (strategy not allowed in authStrategies)`

the jwt strategy attempted in debug is "device-jwt"

if Swap the service functions to

```
export default function (app: Application): void {

  const authentication = new SippAuthService(app, 'authentication');
  authentication.register('jwt', new JWTStrategy());
  authentication.register('local', new LocalStrategy());  

  const deviceAuthentication = new SippDeviceAuthService(app, 'device-authentication');
  deviceAuthentication.register('device-jwt', new DeviceJWTStrategy());
  deviceAuthentication.register('device', new DeviceStrategy());


  app.use('/device-authentication', deviceAuthentication);
  app.use('/authentication', authentication);

  app.configure(expressOauth());
}
```

Just the opposite happens, i will get the same message on the users auth service but it will never reach the device auth service

The error is thrown here

```
///AuthenticationService.authenticate. node_modules/@feathersjs/authentication/src/core.js (204)
    if (!authentication || !authStrategy || !strategyAllowed) {
      const additionalInfo = (!strategy && ' (no `strategy` set)') ||
        (!strategyAllowed && ' (strategy not allowed in authStrategies)') || '';


      // If there are no valid strategies or `authentication` is not an object
      throw new NotAuthenticated('Invalid authentication information' + additionalInfo);
    }
```

and as expected `strategyAllowed` is false because "jwt" is not allowed in "device-jwt"

Is there a better way to go about this? Is there a way to utilize express `next()` functionality to validate the request and pass it to the correct authentication service?